# PHP/MYSQL on WIndows server 500 error

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I have a specific problem on windows 2012 R2 machine. When I enter http://localhost/phpmyadmin, I can access my databases using login and password.

But going to localhost/agro/index.php I get a 500 error on the following line:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "DB_name") or die("Kan niet verbinden :" . mysql_error());
```

What's wrong ??

Regards, Arno

Comment: Check the PHP logs to find out the *actual* error.  `500` is the HTTP code for "something went wrong".  You need to find out *what* went wrong before you can fix it.

Comment: maybe you had php 7, so mysql_connect function not available

Comment: PHP version was indeed the problem. Former server had PHP 5.xx installed, we now installed PHP 7.xx.  We now changed to mysqli and everything works again. 

Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score -1):

500 is HTTP code for Server Error. Might be something went wrong on your Server. Can you please provide additional information such as the error specific.

Can also be because of mysql_connect() is actually deprecated in most of the PHP Versions but in latest versions it is not even supported and in some Versions it shows error while in some it shows error.

I believe below PHP version 5.4. you can use functional mysql without errors

Use MYSQLI instead and if you still get any error then you might have server issue - Make your your credentials are OK

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "******";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: PHP version was indeed the problem. Former server had PHP 5.xx installed, we now installed PHP 7.xx.  We now changed to mysqli and everything works again. 

Thanks for the feedback